# Android - Pausing for a few seconds

Tags: java, android, pong

I've been trying for a while to understand the Handlers thingy in order to pause a game for a few seconds.. no luck so far.

I was hoping if someone could walk me through or show me a complete method that can be adapted to my needs.
which are:
I have a pong like game, when the ball hit either sides of the screen, I want to pause for a few seconds to display the score, and then to resume the game.

Thanks!

Comment: what are you using to develop the game?

Comment: what IDE?
eclipse and java using jdk and android sdk

Comment: are you using any library , andengine, libgdx , Flash ???

Comment: not at the moment.
if it's easier using any of them, I wouldn't mind. but right now, no.

Comment: then what are you you using to animate the ball , calculate time and collusion ?

Comment: drawBitmap, and getting its X and Ys for collision detection.
No time clauclations

Comment: then how are you moving the ball ? when do you change x,y of the ball , there must be some time calculation

Comment: There's a method called update() which gets called before the onDraw() is called and changes the x and ys. I'm new to this, so i'm guessing there are better ways of doing it.. not sure how though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using it would be easier (and more efficient) to use a library like libgdx or andengine to do this but to do it in your current case i suggest a simple solution

on the update method use a bool to know if the ball is paused

```
 update()
 {
    if(!isPaused)
    {
       animateBall();
     }
     ...
 }
```

how to pause the ball

```
pauseBall()
{
   isPaused=true;
   Timer  t= new Timer();
   t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
            isPaused = false;
     }
   }, fewSeconds);
}
```

Comment: And this way, when the pauseBall() gets called, it will just pause the entire game for a fewSeconds, and then resume. cool.
Let's say I want to draw the score while paused.

What if I want during this pause, to draw the score? how can I use the same canvas? should I just use onDraw whithin the run() here?

Comment: you can draw the score outside the scope of  'if(!isPaused)'

don't draw in the run function as it runs on a separate thread